# xcode: share .pch file for 2 targets

Tags: xcode, target, pch

I published lite version of my iPhone-app and is in the store.  Now, I want to add the code for the 'full' version and am stuck at a point.

After adding the second target in the project, the lite version compiles fine, but the full version does not.  This is because the macro defined in _Prefic.pch file is not visible to the full version of the code.

Can a project have multiple .pch files?  If no, how do I specify XCode to share the .pch file with both targets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on your target and choose "Get Info". In the "Build" section search for "Prefix Header" setting and look at its value. Set the value as needed (to a new file or to already existing one).